# Mulesoft Deployment failed with password key-store

Tags: mulesoft

i am running my project with 8.5.0 run time server, during the deployment I am getting below error

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'mule-customer', see below  +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'https.port' in string value "<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="${https.port}" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" protocol="HTTPS">
<tls:context doc:name="TLS Context">
<tls:key-store path="keystore.jks" password="password" keyPassword="password"></tls:key-store>
</tls:context>
</http:listener-config>"
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:212) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:63) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:136) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:58) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.5.jar:3.8.5]
```

Here the configuration.xml file which is referring keysore.jks file in resources direcotry

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="${https.port}"
  doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" protocol="HTTPS">
   <tls:context doc:name="TLS Context">
   <tls:key-store path="keystore.jks" password="password" keyPassword="password"/>  
  </tls:context>
</http:listener-config>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, there is no version 8.5.0 of Mule Runtime. The error shows that it is Mule 3.8.5.

Comment: Apologies typo error 3.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration you show uses a property called `https.port`, however that property has not been defined anywhere in the application or the runtime. You need to define it.

See the documentation on how to define properties through properties files o System properties: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.8/configuring-properties

Note that if you are planning to deploy to CloudHub that value will be overwritten because some properties are predefined in CloudHub.